# Flash not recognizing Actionscript file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, document-class

EDIT: In addition to Nambew's answer, make sure that the default program which opens .as files is set to Flash rather than anything else (my default program was set to Dreamweaver which might've also been causing problems as well.

I am using flash CS5 and went to

```
File -> Publish settings
```

to pick the Document class. My flash file is called

```
CircleExample.fla
```

and is in a folder called

```
CircleExample
```

. In the same folder and same directory as the flash file, I have my actionscript file which is called

```
CircleExample.as
```

which is just this:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class CircleExample extends MovieClip {

        public function CircleExample() {
                // constructor code
            var red:Shape = createCircle( 0xFF0000, 10 );
            red.x = 10;
            red.y = 20;
        }

    }

}
```

Now, for some reason, when I make

```
CircleExample.as
```

my document class and click "validate class definition" it says

```
A definition for the document class could not be found in the classpath, so one will be
automatically generated in the SWF file upon export.
```

Comment: Is you as file in the same directory as your fla file?

Comment: @putvande yup, it is. Do I have to manually set the classpath somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class CircleExample contain error, you can't call the method addChild because your class need to extend Sprite or MovieClip

To see the current class path of your Fla, just go in File -> Publish settings, near Script : Actionscript 3, click the Actionscript settings icon.

Normally the classpath contain "." for current file directory.

The class file sample.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class CircleExample extends MovieClip {

        public function CircleExample() {
            super();

            graphics.beginFill( 0xFF0000 );
            graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 10 );
        }

    }

}
```

In your FLA

```
var circle:CircleExample = new CircleExample();

circle.x = 20;
circle.y = 30;

addChild( circle );
```

Comment: hm okay I updated what my new AS code is. It now gives an error saying "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Shape" and it says "Call to a possibly indefined method createCircle"... shouldn't these work since I imported "flash.display.MovieClip" and since I changed the class to "public class CircleExample extends MovieClip"

Comment: can't find the type because you did not import the class.

Comment: @The_asMan which class? I did "import flash.display.MovieClip;"

Comment: @Nambew Awesome, thanks.. Also, what exactly does calling 'super()' do in this situation?

Comment: "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Shape" means you did not import the Shape class. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html import flash.display.Shape

Comment: @user2817200 if you are going to be doing any kind of decent AS3 programing you need to have a firm grasp on the principles of object oriented programing and how inheritance works, which super() is a part of. Polymorphism is not an easy thing to understand at first, but here is an excellent writeup about it. http://www.developria.com/2009/09/as3-object-oriented-concepts-p.html

Comment: @The_asMan I know inheritence and what not, I was just wondering if calling super(); makes any difference since not calling it does the exact same thing. In your link, there was a line of code which said "public class MyClass extends SomeClass" and it explained that line by saying "MyClass inherits all of the public/protected properties and methods of SomeClass. SomeClass is referred to as the super class of MyClass in this situation". So it automatically already inherits from 'SomeClass' even if you don't call "super();" in the constructer function, right?

Comment: It all depends on the base class really. You can not assume that you will never need super(). For example your base class is MovieClip. Lets override addChild and call CircleExample.addChild(obj:DisplayObject) if we do not call super.addChild(obj) somewhere in there then the obj will never be added to the display list, unless you handling it the function you write, but then what is the point on of inheritance if you never use your inherited methods.

Comment: My IDE just generate super automaticly, you can remove the line.

Comment: there is one exception to the rule and that is constructors. The constructor in the base class MUST be called to init the base class. as a result if you do or don't add super() to your subclass constructor the compiler will add it in.

Comment: By adding in the super() call you will control at which point it is called